# Does boto3 have a credential cache comparable to awscli?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3

With awscli there's a credential cache in ~/.aws/cli/cache which allows me to cache credentials for a while. This is very helpful when using MFA. Does boto3 have a similar capability or do I have to explicitly cache my credentials returned from `session = boto3.session.Session(profile_name='CTO:Admin')`?

Comment: Were you ever able to figure this out?

Answer (score 5):

It is already there.

http://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/guide/configuration.html#assume-role-provider

> When you specify a profile that has IAM role configuration, boto3 will make an AssumeRole call to retrieve temporary credentials. Subsequent boto3 API calls will use the cached temporary credentials until they expire, in which case boto3 will automatically refresh credentials. boto3 does not write these temporary credentials to disk. This means that temporary credentials from the AssumeRole calls are only cached in memory within a single Session. All clients created from that session will share the same temporary credentials.

Comment: The .aws/credentials and .aws/config files are used but **.aws/cli/cache** is not. All caching is in-memory only, so it exists only while the Python script is running, but there's no persistent cache (that I can find) as implemented with JSONFileCache in awscli.

Comment: This example shows you how to set up caching to a file
https://github.com/mixja/boto3-session-cache#update-december-2017

Answer (score 3):

I created a Python library that provides this for you - see https://github.com/mixja/boto3-session-cache

Example:

```
import boto3_session_cache

# This returns a regular boto3 client object with the underlying session configured with local credential cache 
client = boto3_session_cache.client('ecs')
ecs_clusters = client.list_clusters()
```

Comment: Will you please update your answer with the update you have in your library?  It's very useful

Answer (score 2):

To summarise above points, a working example:

```python
from os import path
import os
import sys
import json
import datetime
from distutils.spawn import find_executable
from botocore.exceptions import ProfileNotFound
import boto3
import botocore


def json_encoder(obj):
    """JSON encoder that formats datetimes as ISO8601 format."""
    if isinstance(obj, datetime.datetime):
        return obj.isoformat()
    else:
        return obj


class JSONFileCache(object):
    """JSON file cache.
    This provides a dict like interface that stores JSON serializable
    objects.
    The objects are serialized to JSON and stored in a file.  These
    values can be retrieved at a later time.
    """

    CACHE_DIR = path.expanduser(path.join('~', '.aws', 'ansible-ec2', 'cache'))

    def __init__(self, working_dir=CACHE_DIR):
        self._working_dir = working_dir

    def __contains__(self, cache_key):
        actual_key = self._convert_cache_key(cache_key)
        return path.isfile(actual_key)

    def __getitem__(self, cache_key):
        """Retrieve value from a cache key."""
        actual_key = self._convert_cache_key(cache_key)
        try:
            with open(actual_key) as f:
                return json.load(f)
        except (OSError, ValueError, IOError):
            raise KeyError(cache_key)

    def __setitem__(self, cache_key, value):
        full_key = self._convert_cache_key(cache_key)
        try:
            file_content = json.dumps(value, default=json_encoder)
        except (TypeError, ValueError):
            raise ValueError("Value cannot be cached, must be "
                             "JSON serializable: %s" % value)
        if not path.isdir(self._working_dir):
            os.makedirs(self._working_dir)
        with os.fdopen(os.open(full_key,
                               os.O_WRONLY | os.O_CREAT, 0o600), 'w') as f:
            f.truncate()
            f.write(file_content)

    def _convert_cache_key(self, cache_key):
        full_path = path.join(self._working_dir, cache_key + '.json')
        return full_path


session = boto3.session.Session()

try:
    cred_chain = session._session.get_component('credential_provider')
except ProfileNotFound:
    print "Invalid Profile"
    sys.exit(1)

provider = cred_chain.get_provider('assume-role')
provider.cache = JSONFileCache()

# Do something with the session...
ec2 = session.resource('ec2')
```

Answer (score 1):

Originally, the credential caching and automatic renewing of temporary credentials was part of the AWSCLI but [this commit](https://github.com/boto/botocore/commit/2dae76f52ae63db3304b5933730ea5efaaaf2bfc#diff-dcd72ae45553af71f1ceafb2d4ee5dcf) (and some subsequent ones) moved that functionality to botocore which means it is now available in boto3, as well.

Comment: Is there a method to actually share the ~/.aws/cli/cache files? For lack of a better way, I copied JSONFileCache from awscli/customizations/assumerole.py and I get" "ValueError: Value cannot be cached, must be JSON serializable:" I poked around with json.dumps and the Expiration datetime is what's breaking the serialization. I can kludge up my own version of this serialization, but I'm thinking I must be missing something obvious. Thanks.

Comment: You need to add custom json encoding of `datetime.datetime`. Add the `json_encode` function from [awscli/utils.py](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/blob/3db7be30dfdd76f4e322b83b67af3134ae0b32ac/awscli/utils.py#L129) and add it as a default encoder `json.dumps(value, default=json_encoder)`.